# Using a #submit callback on a textfield

Tags: 8, ajax

We have a need to add 'repeatable fields' to a form based on input provided in a textfield. Usually, we use a 'add another' button to keep track of the number of fields to render in the `buildForm()`, and update that number in a submit callback on the button.

The functionality we want isn't that, though. We have a need so that when somebody enters text into a textfield (other than empty), it adds an additional group of fields below it. We are allowing people to scan barcodes, and every time they scan a barcode into a textfield, we want it to create another group of fields so they can scan another item if they want to.

We attempted to use `#submit` on the textfield, but #submit doesn't appear to trigger on the textfield, as we added a print statement, as well as a `$form-state->set()` in there, and attempt to print out `$form_state->get()` on the form to no avail.

Since you can't update the form_state inside of an ajax callback, we can't figure out a way to achieve what we want to do (Add another group of fields once text is entered into a textarea).

Is there another way we can do this?

(We only allow 10 groups to be added per submission, so as a 'workaround' we dynamically add 10 groups in the buildForm, then use `#states` to hide each one if the previous textfield doesn't have data, but this doesn't allow us to add in a 'remove' button for each textfield so the user can remove text fields they don't want to use.)

Comment: The basic workflow of an Ajax request is to check in the form rebuild `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()` and build a form with as many new form element as you like.

Comment: The 'repeatable fields' angle on this feels like what [Inline Entity Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) would address. These work fine with the States API and also allow you to set a min/max/unlimited number of items.

Comment: This is a completely module based form all generated and functional inside of a buuldForm() method. There are no entities attached to the form.

Comment: And as far as $form_state, Im already getting the trigger element, but I cant update the form state inside of an ajax callback so I can't rebuuld the form with the needed number of fields.

Comment: You can add an ajax enabled submit button with CSS, then use JS to 'click' it on keyup (or on blur or whatever) triggering the #ajax. You can put your submit handler on the submit button.

Comment: There is no need for a submit handler when rebuilding a form via Ajax. Whatever you are trying to do in the submit handler move it to buildForm() checking the triggering element in $form_state.